# Unit-Testing for synchronize method in java using Test-NG

Tags: java, unit-testing

How can I start writing test case for below synchronize java method. Thanks.

```java
public synchronized boolean isUser(String username) {
   if (rememberMeMap.containsKey(username)) {
       long timestamp = rememberMeMap.get(username);
       long curtime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
       if (curtime - timestamp > 1200000) { 
           log.warn("RememberMe");
            return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What would you like to test? The time calculation or synchronization?

Comment: Mainly time calculation. but have to do synchronization also.